# Using FLAG_SECURE stop exo player mirror casting in Redmi devices

Tags: android, security, casting, screenshot

I want to stop screenshot and video play on un secure device so i'm using  `this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);`

above code but after using this mirror casting stop working in Redmi device only sound is playing with black window while it running perfect in Samsung and other device. Any Help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: This is a known issue in a few Chinese manufacturers Xiaomi, Redmi note 4, Cool Pad and other chinese smartphones and its probably because of the custom skin that they use..

Comment: @Narendra_Nath is their any solution for this?